# Radio-кнопки не переключают слайдер

Tags: html, css, reactjs, radio

Создаю компонент слайдера при помощи React.
Псевдокласс `checked` никак не реагирует и не изменяет свойства класса `first`

CSS-файл:

```
  .intro {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #23e3c9;
}

.slider {
  width: 800px;
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slides {
  width: 500%;
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
}

.slides input {
  display: none;
}

.slide {
  width: 20%;
  transition: 2s;
}

.slide img {
  width: 800px;
  height: 500px;
}

.navigation_manual {
  position: absolute;
  width: 800px;
  margin-top: -40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.manual_btn {
  border: 2px solid #40d3dc;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 1s;
}

.manual_btn:not(:last-child){
  margin-right: 40px;
}

.manual_btn:hover{
  background: #40D3DC;
}

#radio1:checked ~ .first{
  margin-left: 0;
}

#radio2:checked ~ .first{
  margin-left: -20%;
}

#radio3:checked ~ .first{
  margin-left: -40%;
}

#radio4:checked ~ .first{
  margin-left: -60%;
}
```

JSX-файл:

````
import React, { Component } from "react";
import s from "./app.component.css";
import img1 from "./../img/1.jpg"
import img2 from "./../img/2.jpg"
import img3 from "./../img/3.jpg"
import img4 from "./../img/4.jpg"
import "./app.component.css";
class MyComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div className={s.intro}>
      <div className={s.slider}>
        <div className={s.slides}>
          <input type="radio" name="radio_btn" id="radio1"></input>
          <input type="radio" name="radio_btn" id="radio2"></input>
          <input type="radio" name="radio_btn" id="radio3"></input>
          <input type="radio" name="radio_btn" id="radio4"></input>

          <div className={`${s.slide} ${s.first}`}>
            <img src={img1} alt="" />
          </div>
          <div className={s.slide}>
            <img src={img2} alt="" />
          </div>
          <div className={s.slide}>
            <img src={img3} alt="" />
          </div>
          <div className={s.slide}>
            <img src={img4} alt="" />
          </div>

          <div className={s.navigation_auto}>
            <div className={s.auto_btn1}></div>
            <div className={s.auto_btn2}></div>
            <div className={s.auto_btn3}></div>
            <div className={s.auto_btn4}></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className={s.navigation_manual}>
          <label htmlFor="radio1" className={s.manual_btn}></label>
          <label htmlFor="radio2" className={s.manual_btn}></label>
          <label htmlFor="radio3" className={s.manual_btn}></label>
          <label htmlFor="radio4" className={s.manual_btn}></label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>;
  }
}
export default MyComponent;
```[![Слайдер][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4pOo.jpg
````

Answer (score 0):

в файле webpack.config.js нужно было установить modules: false и классы указывать без применения css модулей.